# How to get urlValue in Ajax Post OnSuccess function from controller

Tags: ajax

I'm developing an MVC Login application

I wanted to redirect to MainPage URL (Ex:-www.amazon.in) from controller to view once the user is validated successfully

Here my Code

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.StoreNumber, model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MolSignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
     private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        var returnPath = new Uri(returnUrl).AbsolutePath;
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnPath))
        {
            //return Redirect(returnUrl);
            return JavaScript("window.location = 'www.amazon.in'");               
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "StoreRegistration");
    }


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "successOfAddition", OnFailure = "failureOfAddition" }
               ))
        {
        }
<script type="text/javascript">
    function successOfAddition(data) {       
        if (data.MessageType == '') {

        }
    }
    function failureOfAddition(data) {
        debugger;
        showAlert(data.MessageType, data.Message);
    }
</script>
```

Here i want to get the returnUrl value from RedirectToLocal ActionResult method of controller, basically i wanted to redirct the user to new web site on succesfull login.

The below code is not working with Ajax Post

```
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

so I'm trying to use

```
return JavaScript("window.location =  + 'www.amazon.in'");
```

It works fine but instead of hard coding the url value i wanted it to pass to my view on OnSuccess function.

Comment: why do need to use javascript to redirect onsuccess? instead of return JavaScript("window.location = 'www.amazon.in'");  use return Redirect("http://www.amazon.in"); And use normal submit Html.BeginForm instead of ajax form

Comment: I have tried using return Redirect but it's not working actually i got to know while using Ajax Post request, redirect doesn't works

Comment: so use Html.BeginForm

Comment: I need it in Ajax.Beginform

Comment: the reason?And you meant its working fine. so its redirecting it to amazon.in ? what needs to be passed then?

Comment: It got it fixed , i have to return Json from actionresult  case           MolSignInStatus.Success:
                    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    return Json(new { url = returnUrl });